# Сравнение картинок на сходство

Tags: java, машинное-обучение, хеширование

Как сравнить картинку 1 и картинку 2 ?

[image: картинка номер 1] [image: картинка номер 2]

на сходство, причем не обязательно, чтобы они могут отличаться размерами. Так же они не должны быть похожи друг на друга на 100%

И какой материал лучше изучить по этой теме?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Сравнение картинок, которые могут отличаться размером (яркостью, контрастностью и т.п.), можно через **перцептивные хэш-алгоритмы**.

Перцептивные хэши можно сравнивать между собой и делать вывод о степени различия двух наборов данных.

По этому теме есть [статья на хабрахабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/120562/). Также я находил [реализацию этого алгоритма на с++](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/537.html). Для `java` уверен либо есть алгоритмы, либо можно написать, т.к. там нет ничего запредельного.

Тут я опишу общий алгоритм, приведя из статьи на хабре:

> 1. Уменьшить размер. Самый быстрый способ избавиться от высоких частот — уменьшить изображение. В данном случае мы уменьшаем его до 8х8, так
>    что общее число пикселей составляет 64. Можно не заботиться о
>    пропорциях, просто загоняйте его в квадрат восемь на восемь. Таким
>    образом, хэш будет соответствовать всем вариантам изображения,
>    независимо от размера и соотношения сторон.
> 2. Убрать цвет. Маленькое изображение переводится в градации серого, так что хэш уменьшается втрое: с 64 пикселей (64 значения красного, 64
>    зелёного и 64 синего) всего до 64 значений цвета.
> 3. Найти среднее. Вычислите среднее значение для всех 64 цветов.
> 4. Цепочка битов. Это самое забавное: для каждого цвета вы получаете 1 или 0 в зависимости от того, он больше или меньше среднего.
> 5. Постройте хэш. Переведите 64 отдельных бита в одно 64-битное значение. Порядок не имеет значения, если он сохраняется постоянным (я
>    записываю биты слева направо, сверху вниз).
>
> Итоговый хэш не изменится, если картинку масштабировать, сжать или
> растянуть. Изменение яркости или контраста, или даже манипуляции с
> цветами тоже сильно не повлияет на результат. И самое главное: такой
> алгоритм очень быстрый!
>
> Если вам нужно сравнить две картинки, то просто строите хэш для каждой
> из них и подсчитываете количество разных битов (это расстояние
> Хэмминга). Нулевое расстояние означает, что это, скорее всего,
> одинаковые картинки (или вариации одного изображения). Дистанция 5
> означает, что картинки в чём-то отличаются, но в целом всё равно
> довольно близки друг к другу. Если дистанция 10 или больше, то это,
> вероятно, совершенно разные изображения.

---

Итого, чтобы сравнить две картинки:

- Нужно найти перцептивные хэши обеих картинок.
- С помощью расстояния Хэмминга определить степень различия хэшей и на основе различия определить их схожесть.

---

**PS.**

Для [python](/questions/tagged/python) есть библиотека для сравнения картинок [imagehash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash). Я с нею игрался и могу предоставить два примера:

- [Консольный](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/imagehash__examples/find_similar_images__phash.py#L20) (поиск картинок в заданной папке и вывод похожих картинок)
- [Оконный](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/search_for_similar_images__perceptual_hash__phash) (для выбранной картинки было найдено 3 похожих картинки, они были выделены рамкой и помещены в список ниже), скриншот:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для поиска фотки мопсика это работает!  но для задачи автора (распознавание закорючек, нацарапанных мышью на экране), ваш алгоритм совсем не подходит.  тут нужна скелетизация изображения и сравнение получившихся графов.  извиняюсь за некропостинг (какой-то баг на ру-SO - постоянно всплывают вверх древние посты, на англ SO такого нет)