# Сравнение изображений на Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, какие существуют способы сравнения изображений на Python?

Задача состоит в том, чтобы из кучи картинок выявить те, которые максимально похожи друг на друга или идентичны.

Comment: Посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794848/201445 есть такая штука как "перцептивные хэш-алгоритмы"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сравнение картинок на сходство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794837/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be)