# Анализ изображения в окне игры и сравнение на предмет совпадения с картинкой. Готовое решение (библиотека) для Python

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

В окне игры могут появляться надписи, необходимо анализировать изображение в определенной области этого окна и проверять на совпадение с файлом изображения. При этом учитывая определенные погрешности. Существуют ли готовые библиотеки для Python, позволяющие осуществить подобное?

Comment: Возможно, ваш случай - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794837/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be