# Как можно просто сравнить 2 изображения python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Нужно сравнить `2` изображения с одинаковым разрешением, без какого-то хеширования и других сложных штук.

Допустим у меня есть `2` скриншота 200x200 пикселей. Если они полностью одинаковые, то `...` что то происходит (какая-то переменная = True). Изображения я захватываю с помощью:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab 
scr = ImageGrab.grab
```

(ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО с помощью библиотеки `cv2(OpenCV)`).

Пример изображений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Будет разница в одном пикселе и желаемый ваш алгоритм не сработает. Не лучше все-таки сжимать до определенного размера и сравнивать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794848/201445

Comment: а можно ли не сжимать изображения, а распознать какого цвета пиксель в каких-либо координатах? И сравнивать его с сохраненным значением цвета в переменной? @gil9red

Comment: Можно, после разбора pillow или opencv картинка будет массивом с пикселями (значениями или кортежом с значениями, типа `(255, 0, 0)`)

Comment: @gil9red , То есть делаю скриншот с помощью PIL, потом перевожу его cv2 формат с помощью ```imp = cv2.imread("1.png")``` .Что нужно сделать ,что бы получить массив или кортеж?

Comment: Неа, достаточно чем-то одним, у pillow через `getpixel` можно пиксели получать, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/42fc02cce76b5119d3238cd28954f35701ce8fb5/pil_pillow__examples/for_cycle__pixels__array/main.py#L21 , у opencv после `imread`получите массив и сможете через квадратные скобки пиксели: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61563593/5909792

Comment: а можно в нумпи загрузить и вычесть друг их друга, а потом посчитать среднее отклонение

Comment: написал бы пример, но `ImportError: ImageGrab is macOS and Windows only`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать `a = (hash(image1.tobytes()) == hash(image2.tobytes()))` должно работать. Правда это уже с хешированием.